# Wildcard (regex?) search to close up lines in PHP (Notepad++?)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a three line code block, hundreds are scattered throughout one file, here's a representative example:

```
if(DEBUG) {
  $misc->Debug("Here is a debug message");
}
```

I want to collapse these lines, to result in:

```
if(DEBUG) {$misc->Debug("Here is a debug message");}
```

Any program will do, but I figured Notepad++ might be simplest?

Any assistance much appreciated!

Comment: If you have the same code repeated then you can just replace the using Find/Replace in notepad++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Notepad++ use the following regex to find those lines:

**Find what :** 
    `if\s*\(DEBUG\)\s*\{\s*(\$misc->Debug\("[^"]+"\);)\s*\}`

**Replace with :**
    `if\(DEBUG\) {$1}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
if\(DEBUG\)\s*\{\s*([^\r\n]+)\s*\}
```

with subsitution to

```
IF\(DEBUG\){ $1 }
```

Comment: I can see your examples working, and thanks for the feedback, but Notepad++ is returning "Find: Invalid regular expression" ?

Comment: Updated both regexes and tested in notepad++ and it seems to work now.